# CodeIgniter - redirect function not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an authentication function (code added below) but when correct credentials are submitted, the redirect function is not working properly. Firefox is showing "The connection was reset" and Chrome shows "No data received".

Please help.

The line "redirect(base_url() . "index.php/masteradmin/Dashboard");" is the one thats not redirecting.

```
public function AuthenticateUser() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");
    if ($email && $password) {
        $status = $this->mastermodal->ValidateSuperAdmin();
        if (is_array($status)) {
            $this->index($status['Message']);
        } else if ($status) {
            if ($this->session->userdata('table') == 'master') {
                redirect(base_url() . "index.php/masteradmin/Dashboard");
            }
        } else {
            $loginerrormsg = "invalid email or password";
            $this->index($loginerrormsg);
        }
    } else {
        redirect(base_url() . "index.php/masteradmin");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code of your modal

Comment: Is the base URL set in the config with `http:\\` or `https:\\` at the beginning?  If you've not changed that, then it won't see it as a new request and you'll end up with a redirect loop

Comment: Change this `redirect(base_url() . "index.php/masteradmin");` to `redirect('masteradmin/Dashboard');`

Comment: where is your modal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try flowing code

```
    redirect(base_url().'index.php/masteradmin',refresh)
```